# juxtapose 2 images inside viewport, maintaining image ratio and applying same height

Tags: javascript, html, image, math

I need to juxtapose 2 random images, both has dynamic height and width. The 2 images should take up all the width that is available in the browser window and both images should have the same height as the browser window (eg. the only way to fit two very differently sized images would be to adjust their width).

This is how I calculate the ratio of each image:

```
var ratio = [maxWidth / srcWidth, maxHeight / srcHeight];
return ratio = Math.min(ratio[0], ratio[1]);
```

As the size of the viewport might also vary, I need to come up with a solution
that will also works if the height of the window is larger than the width.

I can only imagine something wildly complex as a solution right now, how can I simplify this?

Comment: your code seems fine... What's the issue ?

Comment: GameAlchemis@ updated question

Comment: You cannot fill both full height AND full width, unless you accept to modify the aspect ratio. Question 1 : do you want a) full width, max height b) full height, max width c) max area ( = a or b, depending on the image and the window ) ? Question 2 : Can the two images have two different ratio ?

Comment: 1. Yeah, same height as browser window, maximum width without spoiling ratio of images. (There's an edge case if the browser is in portrait mode, but let's skip that). 2. Yup. The rules would be: Both images should fit inside the browser window, the images should have the same height, but can have different widths, the size of the images should be the maximum possible according to these rules.

Comment: My question was, in fact, not precise enough, i didn't mention cropping : so, since you want full height always, you have to crop some images on the left and right, ok ?

Comment: No cropping. The new calculations for image sizes would be adjusted by their difference in width.

Comment: An example of the problem would be  `img A: 1400 x 800, img B: 800 x 1400` inside a viewport that is either `1000 x 500 or 500 x 1000`.

Comment: It might be just a misunderstanding on my part, but i think your problem has no solution as it is exposed. Full height + no cropping + same aspect ratio is just impossible. Just take your first example : a 1000X500 viewport, and img A. Ratio is 500/800 = 5/8, so width is 1400*5/8 = 875, and 875 is > to 500, so cropping is required. You have to modify your requirements, maybe by adding a constraint on viewport and/or image aspect ratio, so that it is mathematically possible, which -too bad- is the condition of possibility of anything.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being unclear. A. No cropping, images needs to have the same height but keep their own aspect ratio. B. Height (equal height on both images). C. Width is dynamic (just have to fit inside the viewport, in the extreme edge case 'equal' height can be less than viewport).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose the images are `w1` by `h1` and `w2` by `h2`, with a screen that is `ws` by `hs`.  Then rescaling image 2, its dimensions are `w2*h1/h2` by `h1`.  The ratio of the image heights to the screen height is `h1/hs`, while the ratio of the total width to the screen width is `(w1+w2*h1/h2)/ws`.  The larger of these is the ratio by which we want to reduce (the first image - the second is rescaled and then reduced).  If the first argument is larger, it means the images are too tall, and we'll have some blank space on the sides.  If the second argument is larger, we'll have blank space above or below.  In javascript:

```
var heightRatio = image1.height/screenheight;
var widthRatio = (image1.width+image2.width*image1.height/image2.height)/screenwidth;
var ratio = Math.max(heightRatio,widthRatio);
image2.width *= image1.height/(image2.height*ratio);
image1.height /= ratio;
image1.width /= ratio;
image2.height = image1.height;
```

You could also change the order of those and get

```
image1.height /= ratio;
image1.width /= ratio;
image2.width *= image1.height/image2.height;
image2.height = image1.height;
```

But I find that less clear as to what's happening.

Comment: I figured it out yesterday, but your solution is shorter. Thank you.